# How do I get the newline character to be processed so that lines wrap?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have set column to wrap text but if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create a new line I don't get a new line inside the cell. It's like it does not treat the newline at all.

What else do I need to set to make this work?

Comment: @Diogo Please check your edits -- many posts need more than just a "?" appended in their title (e.g. this one had broken formatting for `<enter>`). Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> will create a new line in an Excel field

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to use Alt+Enter to create a new line. Also, when you do that, Excel automatically enables text wrap for the cell.